# Failed to get D-Bus connection: Opération non permise

Tags: linux, centos, systemctl, dbus

I'm using a centos 7 OS,
I have removed `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket` after i accidently removed the `/var/run` folder.
Now when i'm trying to use `systemctl` command i'm getting the error mentioned above.
Note that i'm connecting to this machine using SSH.
So i have two questions:

1. Is there a way to recover the deleted files and particularly the `system_bus_socket`?
2. Does rebooting the machine recover the files. (because i'm afraid that after rebooting, the systemctl won't be able to start the services or i won't be able to connect with SSH)?

Answer (score 1):

The folder `/var/run` is recreated after each reboot.  After reboot, the files are recovered.